# Nodemailer yahoo incorrect login

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I want to send emails from my NodeJs app.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const senderMail = "myemail@yahoo.com";

const emailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'yahoo',
  auth: {
    user: senderMail,
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});

function getMailReceivers(mailReceivers) { // convert the string array to one string
  var receivers = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < mailReceivers.length; i++) {
    receivers += mailReceivers[i];

    if (i < mailReceivers.length - 1)
      receivers += ", ";
  }

  return receivers;
}

function getMailOptions(mailReceivers, subj, content) { // set the options and return them
  return {
    from: senderMail,
    to: getMailReceivers(mailReceivers),
    subject: subj,
    html: content
  };
}

module.exports = {
  sendHtmlMail: function(mailReceivers, subject, html) { // send an email
    emailTransporter.sendMail(getMailOptions(mailReceivers, subject, html), function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log(info.response);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

So I use my **correct login**. I tested it multiple times. I still get this error message

```
Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.0 (#MBR1212) Incorrect username or password.
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:591:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1320:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:356:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:747:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:543:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (...\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:495:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
```

There already is a question here but it got no answer yet

[nodemailer and yahoo failing to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580137/nodemailer-and-yahoo-failing-to-send-email)

I call my mailer by using this code

```
mailer.sendHtmlMail(["email1", "email2", "email3"], "Test Email", "<p>Success!</p>");
```

Answer (score 12):

I recently got my yahoo implementation to work so I thought I'd try to answer your question and share my implementation. You are missing a few fields from your emailTransporter object.

First, you're missing  the **host** field. For yahoo, that field should be **smtp.mail.yahoo.com**

Yahoo requires the **port** to be 465 or 587. 465 worked for me.

You have the **service** field correct.

Lastly, you need a **secure** field. Set it to *false*.

I'm not sure how adding a for loop will effect this but you should try just sending to one email first to make sure it works.

If you'd like, you can add a debugger or logger options. I recommend the logger, it really helped me.

So I would change your emailTransporter object as such:

```
const senderMail = "myemail@yahoo.com";

const emailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
            port: 465,
            service:'yahoo',
            secure: false,
            auth: {
               user: senderMail,
               pass: 'mypassword'
            },
            debug: false,
            logger: true .  <---highly recommend this one here
});
```

Side Note 1: Be sure to change your security options to 'less secure apps' in your yahoo account.

Side note 2: While this worked, it took Yahoo almost **7-10 min** to send one email! Not great for development(or production really),  I switched to Gmail. I hope this helps.

Comment: Currently you have to use an app password instead of your personal password. You can request it on yahoo security settings.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST MUST MUST use APP PASSWORD, NOT personal password, otherwise it will not work.

Usually there is 'how to get app password' for the mail provider OR it is usually located in EMAIL PROGRAMS configuration.

e.g. for  mail.ee   you use your EMAIL and App Password is located under: Options -> Oulook, email programs (tab) -> Show Password (assuming you activated it)